# Got Caucus badge for inactive election

Tags: bug, status-declined, badges, election

I just visited [that notstarted election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4) of 2013 and got awarded the [Caucus badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1973/caucus). The badge description says

> Visited an election during any phase of an **active** election...

Is a notstarted election an active election? I don't think so.

Comment: BTW in case this is a bug and gets fixed: I KEEP MY BADGE!  :)

Comment: You have shown enough interest in the few days just before it starts ;)

Comment: Yes, it's actively nonstarted.

Comment: yeah i also got my Caucus bagde

Comment: thanks for the badge :D

Answer (score 2):

Well, the election goes into the "nonstarted" phase a few days before nominations (basically this means that SE has entered the details for the election into the system). So you can't abuse this to get badges for elections that haven't yet happened, except for the ones which are about to happen.

I don't see why this needs any fixing, it's a trivial thing that causes no harm :/ Almost a pluralization bug :P

Comment: Well, as long as folks come _back_ once it starts it's all good, but I don't see someone getting the badge and not returning to see who nominated, or perhaps nominate themselves.