# Notify on retagging

Tags: feature-request, notifications, notification-bar

A question here on meta for instance may stick around for quite a while. A feature-request  maybe even for months. Then the status (tags) gets changed to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) or [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or whatever and the OP does not get notified.

On a normal post-edit we get a notification but retagging does not count for that. Please add retagging to the edit notifications.

Comment: Doesn't that constitute an edit, of which the OP would be notified? I think I was notified for my questions...

Comment: Today one of my questions got changed (status tag added) and I got no notification about the edit. Maybe retagging does not count as edit?

Comment: @Bart I'm not so sure that OP gets notified about re-tagging.

Comment: I mean [this question of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168610/got-caucus-badge-for-inactive-election). There is an edit visible but I got no notification.

Comment: @tohecz Might be. Perhaps I'm making stuff up again. Sad thing is that I'm convincing myself... ;)

Comment: Come to think of it, perhaps it was the moderator adding an answer to my Meta questions which notified me, instead of the status tag change.

Comment: I don't know if all tag changes really require notification, but I can certainly see adding a notification for mod-only tag changes.

Comment: That's considered trivial edit, same as changing one or two characters for example. It's the mod/dev responsibility to also post at least a comment saying "this has been implemented", ideally full "Nick style" answer with details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't we receive notifications about the addition of moderator-only tags to meta requests? Should we?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319356/why-dont-we-receive-notifications-about-the-addition-of-moderator-only-tags-to)

Comment: Voting to leave this open - this is a [feature-request], while the other is a discussion about the topic in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On main sites, retagging is usually indeed too minor to be worth a notification.

On meta sites however, this is different.

I would like to see the following implemented: (i.e. not exactly the original request here)

- In case a moderator is adding or removing a moderator-only tag (aka "red tag") to/from a question, this will bypass the trivial edit check and always send notification to the OP.
- The above will apply only for meta sites. (Implied, as only meta sites got red tags.)

Worth to mention [a comment I wrote four years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168675/notify-on-retagging#comment653233_168675):

> That's considered trivial edit, same as changing one or two characters for example. It's the mod/dev responsibility to also post at least a comment saying "this has been implemented", ideally full "Nick style" answer with details.

The above is true, but many times a developer posts answer like "This will be fixed soon", then when it's actually fixed, only add the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag and at most edits their answer, neither of those trigger notification. Hence it's a good idea to force notification upon retagging in such case.