# Can we get notifications for when moderator tags are added?

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

One of my questions had [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) added with no comment from the developers or anything. [There isn’t a notification for moderator tags being added or removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319354/399694); if I weren’t paying attention to the question, **I wouldn’t know at all that my feature request were being worked on. Can this be changed so that there is a notification if moderator-only tags are added to or removed from a post?**

Comment: Good request, but I've already posted something similar, and there's been an official response at [Why don't we receive notifications about the addition of moderator-only tags to meta requests? Should we?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319356/why-dont-we-receive-notifications-about-the-addition-of-moderator-only-tags-to)