# Notify users when moderator-only tags are changed on their post, even if the edit is tag-only

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications, moderator-tags

Currently a user is not notified for minor edits to their question, including tag-only edits. Can we make an exception to this rule when the edit involves moderator-only tags, such as the [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) or [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tags?

I think it is helpful to know if your bug got fixed, or it was declined to be fixed or wasn't reproduced. While most of the time staff also post an answer or comment when tagging, in some of those cases they don't leave a response, so the user is never notified of the decision.

**Can we make it so that when an edit involves the addition (or removal) of a moderator only tag, the OP gets a notification of that edit?**

To quote Tim Post in a [prior discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319356/622284):

> [The current behavior is] not good design, mostly because it's based on assumptions that we'd leave a response when putting a status tag on something. But **practically speaking, that's not always possible**, especially when putting status tags on posts closely related to others that warrant receiving them after a bug was fixed, or new functionality, or whatever.

Comment: And perhaps also everyone that followed the post!

Comment: The discussion is old, but this Q&A is super relevant: [Why don't we receive notifications about the addition of moderator-only tags to meta requests? Should we?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319356/622284). A then-community evangelist explained his view and plans for the future.

Comment: Related feature request: [Notify on retagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168675/335251) (not a duplicate, since it's about *all* retagging)

Comment: One common case where a staff member doesn't leave a response when declining a request is if someone's already posted an answer disagreeing with the request and staff have nothing to add. Still, though, a notification would be nice, because a user may possibly never notice the decision and spend a lot of time arguing against the disagreeing answer, which is wasted time because staff have already made their decision.

Comment: A related post of mine: [Please notify authors (and followers) of more edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371014/348196)

Comment: Another case I came across is when a staff member does comment when applying a moderator tag, but on an answer rather than the question. Unless the question author has followed the answer, they will not be notified of the retagging.