# Caucus badges can be earned after an election

Tags: support, badges, election

The [description of the Caucus badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus) says: "Visit an [election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election) during any phase of an active election and have enough reputation to cast a vote. This badge can be awarded multiple times."

At the same time, if we look at the dates when some badges were awarded, it was long after an election. I will use examples from Mathematics, where I noticed this. For example, you can check [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus?userid=156808). The list says that they were awarded this badge in June for [election no. 7](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/7) and [election no. 8](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/8). You might be able to find some other examples [with this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1510159/users-with-badges-of-certain-kind-between-two-dates). (To make them easy to access, I will list also other examples from the linked query that I got for the date range from the beginning of this year until November: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus?userid=164325), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus?userid=127696), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus?userid=775699), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus?userid=454915), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus?userid=118359), [6](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus?userid=789323), [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus?userid=492177), [8](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus?userid=105670), [9](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus?userid=70766), [10](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus?userid=413830).

**Questions.**

- What exactly are the conditions when this happens? Is it enough that somebody visits an old election page and, at the same time, the user does not have a badge for that election?
- Is the fact, that one can get Caucus badge *after* an election by design? If that's the case, shouldn't the phrase "active election" be removed from the description?

---

I have noticed this past question: [Got Caucus badge for inactive election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168610). I think that is a bit different from my question - since that one asks about a nonstarted election.

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, there is an older question asking about this: [Strange behavior of [caucus] badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335091). So if the above cases can be explained by *merging of user accounts* (as suggested in the answer to that question and also in the first comment posted here), then I guess this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and this question can be considered a duplicate.

<sup>I'd say that even if it is a duplicate, it might be worth keeping around — since if somebody notices the same thing and they search for the question, probably from the title of this one they'll immediately see that it is what they want — and if they have the older question among the search results, they have to read a bit more than the title to see what goes on there. In any case, I'll leave the decision, whether this question should be closed as duplicate and — if it is closed — whether it should remain here or be deleted, to other users. I certainly admit, that I should have done better job in looking for older questions with similar topics — and I should have noticed that one.</sup>

Comment: I think this can happen as a result of account merges. That's why you also see the Analytical badge awarded from time to time after the old FAQ page was discontinued in 2013.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Strange behavior of \[caucus\] badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335091)